# dir command does not output properly when using WINAPI in c

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to write a function that executes a command in the cmd and reads the output back to the user, the function must deal with non-ASCII characters and should print them to the screen

I tried to use two methods that I know of, POSIX `_wpopen`,`_popen` and using the WINAPI function like `CreatePipe` with `CreateProcess`, both methods work but when executing the command `dir` and `ipconfig` either one of them work to and I have to change parts of the code to make the other command work which leads to the first command outputting garbage text

the full code for the `CreatePipe` with `CreateProcess` method can be found on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/Sgmu77sj)

I could hardcode the command `dir` in the function so that it uses wide or narrow when `dir` is used but this is not an efficient fix and I didn't test enough commands

I also tested the command `curl https://pastebin.com/raw/JvYZi5A2` and it does output the different languages but when trying to execute `dir` it only outputs `a`

the other method using POSIX way

```
void to_do(wchar_t * cmd)
{
    FILE * fd;
    size_t x;
    if( (fd =_wpopen(cmd, L"rb")) == NULL)
        return ;

    char buff[8192] = {0};
    while (1)
    {
        wchar_t tmp[1024]={0};
        if (fgetws(tmp, 1024, fd))
            wprintf(L"%s",tmp);
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

when swapping the `%s` for `%S` it outputs the `dir` command successfully but does not output the other commands, as far as I understand the output of `dir` is treated as narrow where the output of the other commands is treated as wide

How do I fix this issue of having to check if the command is `dir` or not

Comment: [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73830753/1889329)?

Comment: @IInspectable yes i can't figure out what am i doing wrong, i tried both ways

Comment: "Ask, delete question (including comments), re-ask" isn't quite the model that Stack Overflow is after. I don't know how well the [tour] explains how Stack Overflow is supposed to work, but neither do you, since you never actually took the time to go through it. Maybe now's that time.

Comment: If you're worried that your issue is being buried under a lot of other people's unimportant problems, then "walk a mile in their shoes" and realise that they think your issue far less important than theirs.